# Express define next middlewares on req condition

Tags: node.js, express

Let's say i have something like:

```
function odd1(req, res, next) {
    console.log('odd1');
    return next();
}
function odd2(req, res, next) {
    console.log('odd2');
    return next();
}
function even1(req, res, next) {
    console.log('even1');
    return next();
}
function even2(req, res, next) {
    console.log('even2');
    return next();
}

app.get('/something', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.query.type === 'odd') {
        // return odd1, odd2, next
    }
    // return even1, even2, next
}, (req, res) => {
    console.log('OK');
    return res.send('OK');
});
```

I want to define the next middlewares on a queryparam condition; if the type is 'odd' then continue to odd1, odd2, then send 'OK'; otherwise it goes to even1, even2, then send 'OK'

I've tried something like:

```
app.get('/something', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body.type === 'odd') {
        return odd1(req, res, odd2(req, res, next));
    }
    return even1(req, res, even2(req, res, next));
}, (req, res) => {
    console.log('OK');
    return res.send('OK');
});
```

But it doesn't work properly

```
odd2
OK
odd1
TypeError: next is not a function
```

Is this idea possible to do?

Comment: later may also need odd3, odd4, and etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one line solution :-

Just Replace the third argument when calling `odd1` function with the function that return odd2 for your **next** argument.

Inside the `if` statement, when **type** is **odd** :-

```
...
if ( req.query.type == 'odd') {
  return odd1(req, res, () => odd2(req, res, next));
}
...
```

In this way, you will get the right order i.e.,

```
odd1
odd2
OK
```

The main bug is that you make mistake in 3rd argument when calling `odd1` beacuse it should be a function, but you passed a **expression** i.e., `odd2()` which return `next()`, which is also a [expression](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-expressions-complete-reference/) because it has a `()` sign, which returns the **third argument** of **app.get()** and it returns null.

It means you returned null as the third argument for `odd1` inside the `if` block when **type** is **odd**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
function checkType(type) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.query.type === type) {
      return next();
    }
    return next('route');
  };
}

app.get('/', checkType('odd'),  odd1, odd2, odd3);
app.get('/', checkType('even'), even1, even2);
```

This uses [`next('route')`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.all) in a middleware chain to skip all the remaining middleware (to the next *route* middleware) if the type provided doesn't match the proper type for the chain.

So if `req.query.type` equals `odd`, it will run the `odd1/odd2/odd3` middleware functions. If it's not `odd`, then it will skip to the next route middleware, which also happens to match the same path, and check if type is `even`.

However, with this setup you cannot add `odd/even` middleware functions dynamically, you need to declare them upfront.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be explicit - there's a first middleware that sets the type and all other middlewares check this type

```
function checktype(req, res, next) {
    if ( req.query.type == 'odd' ) {
        req.reqtype = 'odd';
    } else {
        req.reqtype = 'even';
    }
    next();
}

function odd1(req, res, next) {
    if ( req.reqtype == 'odd' )
        console.log('odd1');
    return next();
}
function odd2(req, res, next) {
    if ( req.reqtype == 'odd' )
        console.log('odd2');
    return next();
}
function even1(req, res, next) {
    if ( req.reqtype == 'even' )
        console.log('even1');
    return next();
}
function even2(req, res, next) {
    if ( req.reqtype == 'even' )
        console.log('even2');
    return next();
}

app.get('/', checktype, odd1, odd2, even1, even2, (req, res) => {
    res.end('ok');
})
```

Comment: Honestly, if there is no other choice, i'll use this :D

Comment: There are other choices however, this approach doesn't involve any coupling between middlewares. From the separation of concerns (and single responsibility) this has an advantage over your approach, where each middleware has to know what other middleware to call next.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Abhay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18743013/abhay)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73334247/15797673)

In the end of the day, i do something like:

```
function populateMiddlewares(req, res, next, middlewares) {
    if (middlewares.length > 1) {
        return middlewares.shift()(req, res, () => populateMiddlewares(req, res, next, middlewares));
    }
    return middlewares.shift()(req, res, next);
}

const ifType = (value, trueMiddlewares, falseMiddlewares) => (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.query.type === value) {
        return populateMiddlewares(req, res, next, [...trueMiddlewares]);
    }
    return populateMiddlewares(req, res, next, [...falseMiddlewares]);
};

app.get('/something', ifType('odd', [
    odd1, odd2, odd3, odd4,
], [
    even1, even2,
]), (req, res) => {
    console.log('OK');
    return res.send('OK');
});
```

So i can dynamically put it in my routes